# How to return async data to fl_charts?

Tags: flutter

I have the following code which returns january income from a database in json data. But my issue is to retrieve that income and use it in fl_charts

```
//The Code for getting income on january
Future<Double> getJanuaryPrice() async {
  final response = await http.get('http://10.20.50.15/PropertyManagerConnections/currMonth.php');
   
  var row = json.decode(response.body)[0]['january'];

    return row;
}

//The code snippet for fl_charts bar graph data
 BarChartGroupData(
                  x: 2,
                  barRods: [
                             BarChartRodData(
                                   y: 500000, //I want the getJanuaryIncome to be passed to the y-axis
                                   color: Colors.lightBlueAccent
                  )],
                  showingTooltipIndicators: [0]
),
```

or if anyone knows a package that can accomplish my job would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FutureBuilder and wait for the future to complete, then you can display the data.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getJanuaryPrice() ,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return BarChartGroupData(
      x: 2,
      barRods: [
        BarChartRodData(
          y: snapshot.data, //I want the getJanuaryIncome to be passed to the y-axis
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent
        )],
      showingTooltipIndicators: [0]
      );
    } else {
      // handle loading
      return Container();
    }
  },
),
```